# AS2 to AS3 hitTest Migration

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am stuck in as3 hit test problem. this is the code i wrote in as2. please help me  migrate this in to as3

```
target.hitTest((_x - _width / 2) * (1 / (100 / _root.game._xscale)) + _root.game._x, 
  _y * (1 / (100 / _root.game._yscale)) + _root.game._y, true)
```

Comment: What kind of problems do you have when compiling it for as3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_root, _levelX, etc do exist in AS3. You would need to replace _root with the reference of object that contains "game" object. If "game" object is at stage level, you can use game.stage.prop/meth, for most of things.

Another important thing, _xscale/_yscale accepted percentages as 1 to 100 and so on, whereas scaleX and scaleY accept 0 to 1, and so on.

```
target.hitTestPoint ((x - width/2) * (1/rootApp.scaleX) + rootApp.game.x, y * (1/rootApp.game.scaleY) + rootApp.game.y, true);
```

Where "rootApp" is reference to the object, that holds the "game" displayobject (movieclip, sprite or other).

Hope that helps.

-abdul

Answer (score 1):

In AS3 many variables had your name changed. Did you declared the variables *_x*, *_width*, *_root*, *_xscale*, *_y* and *_yscale*?

If not, then this is your problem, all you got to do is change these for the right new variables: *x*, *width*, *root* (*stage* would be better), *scaleX*, *y* and *scaleY*.

Also, there is no longer *hitTest* method, instead, you should use *hitTestObject* or *hitTestPoint*.

You should also take a look at this url: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/migration.html

Cheers,
CaioToOn!